# #view_comments from URL into jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

When I put [www.test.com#view_comments](http://www.test.com#view_comments) in the URL I want to so show a div not by clicking anything, just by entering it into the URL bar.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work when the page first loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.location.hash == '#view_comments') {
    $('.comments').show();
  }
});
```